# Uninstalling dpdk installed using ninja

Tags: ninja, dpdk

I have installed dpdk 19.08  in ubuntu 18.04 using meson and ninja. I need to install dpdk 20.1.11.How can I uninstall the dpdk installed using ninja.Please share any tutorials related to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have not used a custom path for DPDK install and used meson for building dpdk 19.08, there are 2 ways to do it

1. ignore the libraries installed from DPDK 19.08, simply execute `sudo ninja install`. This overrides all libraries, drivers and include.
2. if want to do it cleanly, go to `DPDK 19.08 build folder`, execute `sudo ninja uninstall`. This will remove your previous installation. Then build Dpdk `20.11.1 LTS and do sudo ninja install`

A good practice is always creating a custom path by `-Dprefix=/opt/dpdk-install/`.

note: If you have used `Makefile` for DPDK-19.08, one can always remove the dpdk folder (if it had been created with `make config -T=[target] -O=[output folder]`

[EDIT-1] clarification based on Dave's comment

meson-ninja `install-uninstall` option I part of cmdline options. This has nothing to DPDK libraries or the environment. So to clarify the steps for uninstalling

1. option-1: within the target folder, the command is `ninja uninstall`
2. option-2: outside the target folder, the command is `ninja -C [target folder] uninstall`

Note: this is not a dpdk option but a ninja option.

Comment: This did not work for me. I see this when running `sudo ninja uninstall`. The instructions for installing DPDK state that you need to specify the directory. For me there was a "build" directory after compiling with meson. So I had to use `sudo ninja build uninstall`

Comment: @Dave I have to disagree with you, if you have used meson (nothing to do with DPDK) and your target folder is build you can execute ninja either within the folder (`sudo ninja uninstall`)  or from external folder (`sudo ninja -C [path to target folder] uninstall`). In your comment option `-C` is missing. Note: this is not a dpdk option but ninja option.